# How to invoke SSPI's 'AcquireCredentialsHandle' with supplied credentials?

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, winapi, sspi

### Background

The [Windows SSPI API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374731(v=vs.85).aspx) is an interface into the Windows security service that allows you to authenticate clients and servers to each other. One of the major uses of the API is to provide Windows Integrated Authentication aka Single Sign-on - applications are able to automatically authenticate users to servers by using the user's credentials from when they logged on.

The normal flow for this process:

- The user logs onto their computer, usually using a username and password.
- The user runs an application that uses SSPI to authenticate the user to a service.
- That application calls [`AcquireCredentialsHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374712(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a handle to the existing credentials the user created when they logged on.
- The application uses the handle returned by `AcquireCredentialsHandle()` to participate in the SSPI authentication cycle with a server, using the [`InitializeSecurityContext()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375506(v=vs.85).aspx) API.
- The application and the server exchange opaque arrays of bytes ('tokens') using the `InitializeSecurityContext()` (client side) and [`AcceptSecurityContext()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374703(v=vs.85).aspx) (server side) APIs to verify each others' tokens and continue the authentication cycle.
- The authentication cycle completes at some point when enough tokens have been passed back and forth.
- The application has authenticated itself on the user's behalf to the server. Authentication is complete.

This is the normal flow for this process when using the API as part of single sign-on.

The signature for `AcquireCredentialsHandle()` is:

```
SECURITY_STATUS SEC_Entry AcquireCredentialsHandle(
  _In_  SEC_CHAR       *pszPrincipal,
  _In_  SEC_CHAR       *pszPackage,
  _In_  ULONG          fCredentialUse,
  _In_  PLUID          pvLogonID,
  _In_  PVOID          pAuthData,
  _In_  SEC_GET_KEY_FN pGetKeyFn,
  _In_  PVOID          pvGetKeyArgument,
  _Out_ PCredHandle    phCredential,
  _Out_ PTimeStamp     ptsExpiry
);
```

When used in the typical Windows Integrated Authentication case as above, the `pAuthData` parameter is usually not provided - a null reference is provided instead.

### Problem

I wish to be able to use `AcquireCredentialsHandle()` in a manner where I provide a username and password to it directly. It would seem to handle this, since the `pAuthData` parameter (which was null above) can be a reference to the [`SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380131(v=vs.85).aspx) structure, which allows you to specify a username and password outright.

I've attempted to invoke `AcquireCredentialsHandle()` this way, providing it a filled out `SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY` structure with my username and password. However, every time I invoke it, I get back success, even if I use made-up usernames or passwords. As a sanity check, I tried invoking `LogonUser()` with the same credentials and they either worked or failed, as expected, depending on whether I gave it a valid username/password combo.

What am I doing wrong? **Why does `AcquireCredentialsHandle()` always return success even with absolutely incorrect credentials?**

Below shows the basics of the code I'm using to invoke `AcquireCredentialsHandle()`:

```
public class SuppliedCredential : Credential
{
    public SuppliedCredential( string securityPackage, CredentialUse use, string username, string domain, string password ) :
        base( securityPackage )
    { 
        Init( use, username, domain, password );
    }

    private void Init( CredentialUse use, string username, string domain, string password )
    {
        // Copy off for the call, since this.SecurityPackage is a property.
        string packageName = this.SecurityPackage;

        TimeStamp rawExpiry = new TimeStamp();

        SecurityStatus status = SecurityStatus.InternalError;

        AuthIdentity auth = new AuthIdentity();

        auth.User = username;
        auth.UserLength = username.Length;
        auth.Domain = domain;
        auth.DomainLength = domain.Length;
        auth.Password = password;
        auth.PasswordLength = password.Length;
        auth.Flags = 0x2; // unicode

        this.Handle = new SafeCredentialHandle();

        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
        try { }
        finally
        {
            status = CredentialNativeMethods.AcquireCredentialsHandle_2(
               "",
               packageName,
               use,
               IntPtr.Zero,
               ref auth,
               IntPtr.Zero,
               IntPtr.Zero,
               ref this.Handle.rawHandle,
               ref rawExpiry
           );
        }

        if( status != SecurityStatus.OK )
        {
            throw new SSPIException( "Failed to call AcquireCredentialHandle", status );
        }

        this.Expiry = rawExpiry.ToDateTime();
    }
}

...

[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
public struct AuthIdentity
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string User;
    public int UserLength;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string Domain;
    public int DomainLength;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string Password;
    public int PasswordLength;
    public int Flags;
};

...

[ReliabilityContract( Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail )]
[DllImport( "Secur32.dll", EntryPoint = "AcquireCredentialsHandle", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode )]
internal static extern SecurityStatus AcquireCredentialsHandle_2(
    string principleName,
    string packageName,
    CredentialUse credentialUse,
    IntPtr loginId,
    ref AuthIdentity packageData,
    IntPtr getKeyFunc,
    IntPtr getKeyData,
    ref RawSspiHandle credentialHandle,
    ref TimeStamp expiry
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### In short

`AcquireCredentialsHandle()` returns true even if the credentials are bogus; only when the client attempts to invoke `InitializeSecurityContext()` does the API validate the username and password. `AcquireCredentialsHandle()` just performs parameter validation (pointers values are valid, structures are filled out correctly, parameters make sense with each other, etc). Since I correctly provided incorrect parameters, `AcquireCredentialsHandle()` didn't care.

...

#### In long

To summarize, the normal cycle for an client application to participate in SSPI authentication is the following:

- Client calls some form of `AcquireCredentialsHandle()`.
- Client invoke `InitializeSecurityContext()`, which returns some token to send to the server.
- Server takes the received token and invokes `AcceptSecurityContext()`, returning some token to send back to the client.
- The client receives the token and invokes `InitializeSecurityContext()`.
- ... the loop continues until the authentication cycle has completed between both ends.

In the above situation, credentials acquired from calling `AcquireCredentialsHandle()` with a provided `SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY` structure (in turn filled out with a valid username, domain, and password) aren't validated on the client side until the client invokes `InitializeSecurityContext()` the first time, before it sends its first token to the server.

In response to a similar question, Dave Christiansen (a Microsoft employee?) [posted the following](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/microsoft.public.platformsdk.security/acquirecredentialshandle$20SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY%7Csort:relevance/microsoft.public.platformsdk.security/GeQO8R2gPsA/O-ZVZcYQDb4J) in the newsgroup 'microsoft.public.platformsdk.security' on 19-Sept-2003:

> How are you determining that the credentials are those of the local
> user? SSPI is sometimes tricky this way. What package are you using
> (Sounds like NTLM, Kerberos, or Negotiate if you're using
> SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY)?
>
> Note that AcquireCredentialsHandle will succeed even if the
> credentials given are incorrect (e.g. wrong password), because it
> doesn't actually use them until you call InitializeSecurityContext.